# css transform scale mouse is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

i am trying to draw in canvas with transforming the div size
but i am not able to draw exactly from mouse point, there is some distance between mouse and line where is actual drawing happen.

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    transform: scale(0.5)
}
```

**JS**

```
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function (e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
};
el.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (isDrawing) {
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};

el.onmouseup = function () {
    isDrawing = false;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvarshney/Lqbeqjzb/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to subtract the left and top of the canvas from the mouse positions and multiply everything by 2 (or the reciprocal of whatever your scale is).

```
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

// code here
ctx.moveTo((e.clientX - rect.left) * 2, (e.clientY - rect.top) * 2);

// code here
ctx.lineTo((e.clientX - rect.left) * 2, (e.clientY - rect.top) * 2);
```

Updated jsfiddle here -->http://jsfiddle.net/Lqbeqjzb/7/

EDIT: Made changes to your fiddle based on the comment --> https://jsfiddle.net/pb5ckhjm/4/

Comment: Can you please have a look at this code: https://jsfiddle.net/vishalvarshney/pb5ckhjm/2/

Comment: yup, this is working but there is a bug is the solution, we cant able to draw line from one end to another end it  stops at appx. 75% have a look at http://imgur.com/S7zjpP1

Comment: That is because your canvasDiv is wider than your canvas. canvasDiv width is 50% of the document (because of scale(0.5)). While canvas width is a constant 300px. Do an inspect element on the canvas and you'll understand the difference in widths.

Comment: thank you, my friend, your formula help me figured how to change my formula to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mouseover

```
el.onmouseover = function (e) {
isDrawing = true;
ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
 };
```

Let me know this is what you want

Comment: nope, it is not working and by this way drawing is made independent to click , you cant draw correctly